# Erlang Insert tuples in a list

Tags: erlang, tuples

Here is an example, what I'm trying to achieve:

**CASE I**

```
>Fn = fun(X) -> {X, 3} end.
>A = {{1,2}, {3, 4}, Fn(8)}.
>{{1,2},{3,4},{8,3}}
```

This worked pretty well.But in case of multiple tuples

**CASE II**

```
>Fn2 = fun(X) -> {X, 3},{7,5} end. 
>A1 = {{1,2}, {3, 4}, Fn2(8)}.
>{{1,2},{3,4},{7,5}}
```

Please suggest me the solution so that I can achieve following result for **CASE II**

```
>{{1,2},{3,4},{8, 3}, {7,5}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, to explain what happens in the second case: when you write `Fn2 = fun(X) -> {X, 3},{7,5} end`, it means "given `X`, create and throw away tuple `{X, 3}`, then return tuple `{7, 5}`.

You also seem to be confusing tuples and lists. Tuples aren't used like this; they are for fixed size structures. If you actually want to get a list, it's easy:

```
> Fn2 = fun(X) -> [{X, 3},{7,5}] end. 
> A1 = [{1,2}, {3, 4}] ++ Fn2(8).
[{1,2},{3,4},{8,3},{7,5}]
> A2 = [{1,2}] ++ Fn2(8) ++ [{3, 4}].
[{1,2},{8,3},{7,5},{3,4}]
> A3 = Fn2(8) ++ [{1,2}, {3, 4}].
[{8,3},{7,5},{1,2},{3,4}]
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I understand it now. One more query - Can I put `Fn2(8)` on specific position at 1st or at 2nd position or at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use list ([ ... ]) instead of tuple ( { ... }):

```
> Fn3 = fun(X) -> [{X, 3},{7,5}] end.
> [{1,2}, {3, 4}| Fn3(8)].            
[{1,2},{3,4},{8,3},{7,5}]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!  
Can I put Fn3(8) on specific position at 1st or at 2nd position or at the end.